# Identify the referrer domain in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a web site which has 2 domains

ex : www.site1.com
     www.site2.com (which will forward to www.site1.com with domain
masking)

www.site1.com is where the actual web server rungs

www.site2.com is just a domain name forwarder and I use mask to make
the user feel he/she is in www.site2.com even though he/she is in
www.site1.com

But in underlying code I want to distinguish  both the request (who
came from www.site1.com and who came from www.site2.com) so that I can
load their UI accrodingly

I tried request.host as well as request.referrer which always gives
www.site1.com

and when I get the source code of the www.site2.com (which redirects
to site1) it has this,

sameera gayan

So what is the best option for getting the 2 different site URL's ,

thanks in advance

cheers,
Sameera

Comment: "and when I get the source code of the www.site2.com (which redirects to site1) it has this,
sameera gayan "
What does this part of the question mean?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, "and when I get the source code of the www.site2.com (which redirects to site1) it has this," means I typed the url www.site2.com in the browser and it redirected to www.site1.com, so i took the html source of the page which I posted thanks,
sameera

Comment: Basically site2.com is loading a frame with the contents of site1.com in it. You are asking how to get the parent frame's site address, which I don't think you can since that information isn't sent to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a static IP, you could set up www.site2.com to point to the IP address, instead of the other domain name.

Another option is to create a third name as a subdomain of site1.com, such as site2.site1.com that points to the same place as www.site1.com. Then forward www.site2.com to site2.site1.com. You would then be able to pick up that alias.